# Why can't I get a spark?

Tags: electrical, sparkplugs, ignition-coil, stator

I have an early 70's Honda SL125 engine and I'm trying to wire it up so that it can run without the battery. I found this guide http://waynescyclegarage.mysite.com/custom.html and I've followed it and done just what it says, but I'm not getting any spark. I used a voltage meter on the stator and there seems to be no issues with that. I also put one wire of the meter on the wire going into the coil and the other on the spark plug and when I use the kick starter it comes up with something on the voltage meter, but despite all that, I still get no spark. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: You must have a battery.  It smooths out dangerous voltage spikes from the alternator, among other things.

Comment: @RobertS.Barnes Old motorbikes never used to have batteries, they used a magneto to generate the spark for the ignition.

Comment: Magnetos ( small engines like lawn mowers, etc.) don't use batteries. The magneto generates a low voltage DC pulse which goes through the built in coil which substantially increases the voltage, which then goes in the high voltage wire to the plug.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up getting it sparking. I didn't have the pink wire grounded properly.